# Why is my node.js server not working under iisnode?

Tags: node.js, iisnode

I'm trying to run a node server in IIS 10 using iisnode, but it's not working.

I followed this guide here exactly:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUYCDnqR8p0

My main node server file is app.js and it looks like this:

```
const exp = require('express');
const contactRoutes = require('./routes/contact');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = exp();
const port = 3000; //process.env.PORT;
const corsOptions = {
  origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://www.assertivesolutions.ca', 'https://www.assertivesolutions.ca'],
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
};


app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('GET: Express is workinging on IISNode.');
});
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('POST: Express is workinging on IISNode.');
});

app.listen(port);

module.exports = app;
```

I have my website setup in IIS to listen on port 3000.

Here is web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>

<!-- indicates that the app.js file is a node.js application 
to be handled by the iisnode module -->

<handlers>
  <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
</handlers>

<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="sendToNode">
            <match url="/*" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>

<iisnode devErrorsEnabled="false" />

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I try to go to localhost:3000 in the browser on my server (Windows Server 2019), all I see is this:

[image]

When I try with postman from my home computer, it just returns this (GET or POST):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>500 - Internal server error.</title>
<style type="text/css">
    < !-- body {
        margin: 0;
        font-size: .7em;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        background: #EEEEEE;
    }

    fieldset {
        padding: 0 15px 10px 15px;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 2.4em;
        margin: 0;
        color: #FFF;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 1.7em;
        margin: 0;
        color: #CC0000;
    }

    h3 {
        font-size: 1.2em;
        margin: 10px 0 0 0;
        color: #000000;
    }

    #header {
        width: 96%;
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
        padding: 6px 2% 6px 2%;
        font-family: "trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
        color: #FFF;
        background-color: #555555;
    }

    #content {
        margin: 0 0 0 2%;
        position: relative;
    }

    .content-container {
        background: #FFF;
        width: 96%;
        margin-top: 8px;
        padding: 10px;
        position: relative;
    }

    -->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
    <h1>Server Error</h1>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div class="content-container">
        <fieldset>
            <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
            <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Finally, when I look at the iisnode logs, I see this:

```
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:3000
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1284:19)
at listenInCluster (net.js:1349:12)
at Server.listen (net.js:1437:7)
at Function.listen (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\assertivesolutions\backend\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\assertivesolutions\backend\app.js:22:5)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
```

I tried to resolve the permissions issue by giving everyone full access from the wwwroot folder level, but I still get the same error.

Any help troubleshooting this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the server can't start the node process because it is listening to port 3000 and you have also hardcoded your node.js code to use port 3000 (how iisnode work is iis will listen to a port then forward each request to your node process via HTTP to the node application's port - your OS will not allow two or more server applications, eg Apache and IIS and minecraft, to use the same port)

Comment: That worked! Setting the port to process.env.PORT seemed to solve the problem. Thanks slebetman.